# Showing that Lagrange Basis Polynomials sum to 1

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

I am currently trying to explain why it is the case that when given a Lagrange polynomial with coefficients of all $1$

$P_3(x)$ $=$ $L_0(x)$ + $L_1(x)$ + $L_2(x)$ + $L_3(x)$ $=$ $1$, for all $x$.

What I think I know is that when we are given n+1 data, then there exists a polynomial that passes through all of these data points, and this is simply just $y = 1$?

I'm having a really hard time intuitively understanding what exactly this means. Any guidance in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrange polynomial for point $x_i$ in interpolating $f(x)$ at $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, doesn't depend on values of $f$ at these points. the respective interpolated polynomial would be $p(x) = \sum_{i} f(x_i) L_i(x)$. so for any set of points $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ you can always interpolate function $f(x)=1$ which is indeed a polynomial (of degree 0) and its interpolation is equal to itself. in this case the interpolated polynomial becomes:
$$
1= f(x) = p(x) = \sum_i f(x_i) L_i(x) = \sum_i L_i(x). \square
$$

you can actually prove a lot of relations for lagrange polynomials with these kind of technique, e.g:
$$
\sum_i \frac{d}{dx}L_i(x) = 0 \\
\sum_i x_i^k L_i(x) = x^k \qquad k\leq n
$$

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question before seeing this. I believe this essentially the conclusion I had came to. If I understand correctly.